# 2.4 Proposition of Chapter 5 in do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Picture below is from the section 2 of Chapter 5 of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. I can't calculate the red lines.

What I try:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(t,0) = (d\exp_p)_{\frac{t}{a}v(0)} \frac{t}{a}v'(0)
=
(d\exp_p)_{tv} \frac{t}{a}\omega
$$
why in the first red line, there is not $\frac{1}{a}$ ?

Besides, I find the Lee's book. There is not a similar proposition.  In fact, I feel this proposition has flow.

> [image]

Comment: Indeed it should be something like $f(s,t)=\exp_p(\frac{t}av(as))$ instead.

Comment: @user10354138  Thanks.